# Let $R = \mathbb{Z_5]x]}/(3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{Z_5[x]}/(3)$

1. Is $R$ undefined or the empty set? As $3$ has degree $0$ and the elements in $R$ have degree less than $deg(3)$ it seems that would be the case?
2. Is $x^2 + 2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z_5}$? Now, $x^2 + 2 = 0 \implies x^2 = -2 \implies x^2 = 3$ and this can't be satisfied by any integer in $\mathbb{Z_5}$, hence $x^2 + 2$ is irreducible?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(3)$???

Comment: Note that $3\cdot 2 \equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so the ideal $(3)$ is all of $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z_5$, so the ideal it generates is the entire ring.  The quotient $R$ is just the zero ring.